# Making a six digit pin system more secure at the back end

Tags: php, json, security, aes

I'm developing a password manager which has two forms of authentication.

First the user logs in using their password. I have this working securely using bcrypt.

The next part is far more tricky. The user's saved services are stored in a JSON format like so:

```
{
     "name":"facebook",
     "login":"myemail@email.com",
     "signup-email":"myemail@email.com",
     "password":"121654754321",
     "notes":"my security questions answer is \"blah blah blah\""
}
```

I plan to store this in a DB table with two fields: id, and data(the AES256 encrypted JSON).

So far my design is using a 6 digit pin with a 32 char salt (unique to each user) to encrypt this. the pin is never stored. the salt is stored in the user table.

What are the possible flaws in doing it this way? Can anyone recommend a better way to implement this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security, use http://security.stackexchange.com instead. Describe your protocol clearly though, including countermeasures and what's being done by who.

Comment: Note that it is hard enough for users to remember one password. If you have a single system that requires both a password and a PIN, you're in trouble already. Furthermore, online authentication can be implemented using counter measures (3 times, you're out!). Decryption cannot. So if you keep to this scheme, your encryption password should be stronger than the one used for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The risk

Your systems poses a great security challenge, since it acts as a central password repository, thus making it a choice target. Your best defence is ignorance: if you can't decode it, an attacker would have a hard time doing it too. Also, you don't need access to the data stored, but the user (and only the user) does.

What you've done/intend to do is on the right track since you don't have access to the full key. But why do you use a 6-digit pin instead of a "standard" password/phrase? You're responsible for the security of over 80% of the encryption key, and you've got all of them in one single place! An attacker just needs to figure out the (quite weak) pin to add to the salt in order to read the data. Plus, if your system gets compromized, one could manage to retrieve user requests in order to extract the pins and gain access to your user's accounts.

## (some) Tips

What could you do then? I'm no expert in security, but I know some tricks. I'll try to answer to the best of my abilities.

### Delegate decryption to the end-user

If the decryption key never gets close to your system, the data would be way safer. In order to retrieve a user's passlist, one would need to break into this user's computer and somehow retrieve the decrypted data off the page. That's totally doable, maybe easier than breaking into your server in some case, but this would only grant access to only one account. That's quite good for your other users :D

There's a growing number of applications using this approach to acheive similar results. You often see client-side AES decryption done with JavaScript for instance. The [zerobin project](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=php%3azerobin) describes such a mechanism.

### Use strong encryption keys

As said earlier, leaving the user only 6 bytes in the encryption key isn't really robust. They need to be able to add as much entropy they like. Passwords with an upper size limit are often a bad idea (I personally hate those who tell me how *short* my password has to be).

### Have a look at [key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)

(This point is related to the previous)

Key stretching describes an operation taking a standard "human" password and transforms it into a stronger encryption key. It has many applications, and is in use in several password managers of the kind you're building.

RSA's [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) is a well-known key stretching algorithm used in many security applications.

## Side notes

Of course there are several other points you need to address in order to build a secure system:

- Obviously, you **NEED** to enforce SSL (HTTPS) communications between your server and your clients ;
- Access to your server needs to be well protected in order to protect the secrets used for encryption. Client-side decryption greatly reduces the threats posed by break-ins, but that doesn't mean they shouldn't be protected. This implies fine tuned firewalls, up-to-date applications, reactivity to security fixes, etc. ;
- You need to teach a thing or two to your users about security. It's well known that both ends of a channel have to be secured in order for the channel itself to be secure too.
- There are probably many other concerns, but hey, this isn't a lecture on security ;-)

Comment: Why are you recommending PBKDF2 if the user already made clear that bcrypt is used?

Comment: I simply wasn't familiar with bcrypt. Technically, I was recommending key-stretching algorithms, and I quoted PBKDF2 among those. But if the OP already uses bcrypt, then this particular suggestion is already fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

The pin is known and inserted only by the user? Instead of using the 6 digits pin + salt for encrypting the data you can use PBKDF2 (Password-Based Key Derivation Function) to generate a secure encryption key based on that 6 digits pin (and the salt). This way each user will have a different (and secure) encryption key. Mind that along with this you should always use a different and cryptographically secure generated IV that can be appended (or prepended) to the encrypted data.

The security flaws of your implementation are that there is the possibility of not having enough entropy generated by your pin + salt and since you didn't talk about an IV I suppose you are not using one thus exposing possible patterns in your encrypted data.

For the security flaws my implementation has instead, depends on what are your security objectives. For most people PBKDF2 (+ one of the `hash_algos()` algorithm as per the PHP implementation) is secure enough, even if it is more exposed to attacks using FPGA or GPU clusters. If you want to avoid them, you can use bcrypt to generate a key that is harder to attack using these technologies.

I recommend you to read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415) that gives more in-depth reasons on why bcrypt is somewhat better than PBKDF2

Comment: Why are you recommending PBKDF2 if the user already made clear that bcrypt is used?